# Using Ractive.js, how do you Unselect a selected select box?

Tags: ractivejs

I am using Ractive.js v0.7.3, and I have a need to unselect a select box, but cannot find in the Ractive documentation how to do it.

In my select, the first option is empty (has no value and says "Select..."), so I  tried setting the value to null like so:

```
rjs.set('selected.' + cfg.nodeType + '.id', null);
```

and even verified that it was updating the value by doing the following before and after:

```
var test = rjs.get('selected.' + cfg.nodeType + '.id');
```

which returned the correct id before and null after, but the prior value still displayed as selected in the UI.

I ended up using the following in jQuery:

```
function resetMenu(cfg) {
    $('#' + cfg.nodeType + 'Select').attr('selectedIndex', -1)
        .find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);
}
```

but then when I switch to new page, Ractive 'reselects' the former selection. So, I added the following thinking that Ractive didn't know about the change, but Ractive still 'reselects' the former selected value.

```
function resetMenu(cfg) {
    $('#' + cfg.nodeType + 'Select').attr('selectedIndex', -1)
        .find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);

    if (rjs) {
        rjs.update('navList.' + cfg.nodeType);
    }
}
```

I am thinking that if I could use Ractive to unselect the option, that would be ideal, but I cannot find in the Ractive.js documentation how to unselect a select option.

Comment: If the provided answer doesn't work for you, please clarify what exactly you do differently, or even better, update the provided demo to show when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

The bug in Ractive has been fixed. In the edge version (v0.8.0), you can now `ractive.set()` any value, and if there's no matching option, nothing will be selected.

**Original answer:**

If there's no option matching the set value, Ractive will select the first option. This happens each time the select is updated. I believe it's a bug and  have filed an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2494).

Currently, the best option is creating a decorator to handle the deselecting:

```html
{{selected}}<br>

<select value="{{selected}}" decorator="unselect: {{selected}}">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  template: '#template',
  data: { selected: null },
  decorators: {
    unselect: function (select, value) {
      // use ractive.set('selected', null) in your code to unselect
      if (value === null) {
        select.selectedIndex = -1;
        this.updateModel();
      }

      return {
        teardown: function () {}
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xubo91oh/

Comment: When is version 0.8 due as a stable release? The web site is currently offering version 0.7.3

Comment: 0.7.3. is the latest stable. 0.8.0 will be released... when it's done. We don't have any ETA, I'm afraid. You can follow the project on GitHub for more info. In the meantime, the workaround provided in my answer should work pretty well - if it does, please mark this as the accepted answer.